# Databinding between no GUI Objects,

Tags: c#, data-binding

Thank you for reading,

I have two classes with two propertys. I would like to bind them. Is this possible or ist Databinding just between an Object an an GUI Element.

Cause everytime i bind the is an exeption that it cant be bind to this obejct cause there will be an exeption:

"An die Eigenschaft SelectedVariable für das Zielsteuerelement kann nicht gebunden werden.
Parametername: PropertyName"*

Hope you can help,

Thomas

*something like: The Property of the selectedVariable cant be binded on the targetelement. Parametername: PropertyName.

Comment: I want to do the same thing, are Events the solution? No .NET tools for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using the `Binding` class from the `System.Windows.Data` namespace, then you cannot just bind two objects together.

The source of the Binding can be a property on a POCO, but the Target needs to be a [DependencyProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.aspx) on a [DependencyObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.aspx)

so in essence, yes - its a GUI technology.

Comment: thank you, yes i do use bindding.add(...) so i have to use events :(